# I try to integrate my mlmodel into my app but error shows

Tags: swift

I try to integrate my coremlmodel into my hand pose classifier app but it show some error

`private let model = VNCoreMLModel(for: Digits().model)`

and the errors is
**'init()' is deprecated: Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.**

Comment: Did you check the answer here? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671446

Comment: @jnk.sch but how do I VNCoreMLRequest it, it needs VNCoreMLModel